# Convergence of a Series with Infinitely Many Increasing Terms

Tags: sequences-and-series, analysis

I'm working on the following problem:

Let $\{ c_n \}_{n=1}^{\infty}$ be a sequence such that $c_n = \frac{1}{n^2}$ if $n$ is odd, and $c_n = \frac{1}{n^4}$ if $n$ is even. Prove that (i) $c_{n+1} > c_n$ for infinitely many $n$ and (ii) $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} (-1)^{n-1} c_n$ converges.

My attempt:

(i) We claim that when $n$ is even, 
$$c_{n+1} > c_n$$
and proceed via induction. First, note that for $n=2$, 
$$c_3 = \frac{1}{9} > \frac{1}{16} = c_2.$$
Now, suppose that $c_{k+1} > c_k$ for some even $k$. Then, we prove that 
\begin{align*}
c_{k+3} &> c_{k+2} \\
\frac{1}{(k+3)^2} &> \frac{1}{(k+2)^4} \\
\end{align*}
by showing that 
$$(k+2)^4 > (k+3)^2.$$
Accordingly,
\begin{align*}
(k+2)^4 &= k^4 + 8k^3 + 24k^2 + 32k + 16 \\
&>^{I.H.} (k^2 + 2k + 1) + 8k^3 + 24k^2 + 32k + 16 \\
&= 8k^3 + 25k^2 + 34k + 17. \\
\end{align*}
Now,
\begin{align*}
8k^3 + 25k^2 + 34k + 17 &> (k+3)^2 \\
\Rightarrow 8k^3 + 24k^2 + 28k + 8 &> 0 \\
\end{align*}
holds as $k>0$ and each coefficient of the polynomial is positive. Thus, $c_{n+1} > c_n$ for each even $n$.

(ii) To see that $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} (-1)^{n-1} c_n$ converges, we first note that

$$ |(-1)^{n-1} c_n | = c_n \leq \frac{1}{n^2} \qquad \forall n \in \mathbb{N} $$

Further, $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n^2}$ converges via $p$-Test with $p = 2 > 1$, so

$$ \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} (-1)^{n-1} c_n $$

converges via the Weierstrass M-test.

Is this sound reasoning? The inductive portion seems long, as the result is somewhat intuitive. Is there an shorter way to prove this?

Comment: Everything sounds good to me! For the first part it should be faster without induction: Just show that $1/(2k+1)^2 > 1/(2k)^4$, equivalently $2k+1 < (2k)^2$.

Comment: At the end, by "the Weierstrass M-test", don't you mean the comparison test? I thought the Weierstrass M-test was a test for uniform convergence of a series of functions?

Comment: @bof That's a good point. I seem to remember one of my old analysis instructors handing out a generalized M-test handout that wasn't restricted to series of functions, but I may be misremembering. Either way, comparison seems to check out just as well here. Thanks!